# Powershell - Secure String for Passwords and SFTP

Tags: powershell, sftp

I am trying to implement a way to use a stored secure string so that my SFTP password is not visiable in the script.  For example, I'd like to generate a variable $password that could be used instead.  I found the following examples online but I can't get them to work unfortunately.  I've done something similar in the past but can find my notes or links to the website that explained how to complete the task.

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\securestring.txt 
$pass = cat C:\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "test",$pass
```

Here is my script.  Here is a link to the snapin if anyone is interested.  http://www.k-tools.nl/index.php/sftp-in-powershell/

```
#Add the SFTP snap-in
Add-PSSnapin KTools.PowerShell.SFTP

#Define some variables
$sftpHost = "ftp.domain.com"
$userName = "user"
$userPassword = "password"

$localFile = "C:\bin\emp1.xlsx"

#Open the SFTP connection
$sftp = Open-SFTPServer -serverAddress $sftpHost -userName $userName -userPassword $userPassword

#Upload the local file to the root folder on the SFTP server
$sftp.Put($localFile)

#Close the SFTP connection
$sftp.Close()
```

Again, thanks for everyones help!

UPDATE

I tried this:

```
$pass = cat c:\bin\ftpcreds.txt | convertto-securestring
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "usertest1",$pass
$sftpHost = "ftp.domain.com"
$userName = $mycred.username
$userPassword = $mycred.password
$sftp = Open-SFTPServer -serverAddress $sftpHost -userName $userName -userPassword $userPassword
$sftp.Put($localFile)
$sftp.Close()
```

And get this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSchException] doesn't contain a method named 'Put'.
At C:\bin\SFTP Upload Samples.ps1:21 char:1
+ $sftp.Put($localFile)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.JSchException] doesn't contain a method named 'Close'.
At C:\bin\SFTP Upload Samples.ps1:36 char:1
+ $sftp.Close()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What seems to be your problem? It looks like you found all the information you need. Just change `-username $mycred.username` and `-userPassword $mycred.password` There are plenty of website covering powershell credentials, maybe not open-sftpserver but that shouldnt be an issue. I suggest a little more research

Comment: How is it not working?  Are you getting some sort of error you could share with us?

Comment: I updated the post with what I tried and the error I received.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the snap-in returns the exception as the result instead of letting it bubble up, bad design choice IMHO.

Comment: This is the first SFTP solution I've used. If there any other suggestions for SFTP with Powershell that could use a secure string I'd be open to giving it a go.

Answer (score 1):

If your SFTP is wanting to use a decrypted version of your secured password then you'll want to extract it from your $mycred by:

```
$userpassword = $mycred.getnetworkcredential().password.tostring()
```